# Editing child data within parent form (see screenshot for example)

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have two related tables - let's say they are called Company and Staff. A Company can have many Staff. In the CRUD edit for a company, I want to be able to add and remove staff right inside that form. I am having a hard time finding this covered anywhere, but there is something very similar in this screenshot from the documentation about an unrelated feature. What magic is this?

See example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuwXZ.png

Comment: :-) What you're seeing there is the ```table``` field type, which does NOT support relationships. It just stores the data as JSON in a db column.

Comment: I'm afraid Backpack doesn't have CRUD inside CRUDs right now, and we haven't started working on it yet. We do have plans for it, we call it the ```matrix``` field type, but it's nowhere near completion. I think it's something we'll only have in version 4. Until then, you can change the ```table``` field to fit your needs, for each use case. Bummer, I know...

Comment: Thanks man, I can work with that! I'll probably just create a separate CRUD form for them to enter the Staff data with a select to allow them to link to the Company.

I love what you've been doing. I'm working on a very large project and your software has saved me oodles of time and effort. Great job!